# Tensorboard pointing wrong data loction

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am working on the jupyter notebook environment and made a hyperparameter tuning process using HParams. I planned to use tensorboard to inspect patterns in hyperparameter values but tensorboard kept opening old files(logs/Twitter_sentiment_analysis) and threw the shown error in the image.

When I enter other file names(files that don't exist) such as

```
%load_ext tensorboard 
%tensorboard --logdir logs/nothing

>>>
ERROR: Timed out waiting for TensorBoard to start. It may still be running as pid 35232.
```

I get a usual time out error. Please help me with my problem.

Thank you. 
[image]

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same problem, did you fix the time-out and log path?

Answer (score 1):

The notebook actually tells you what to do. There is already one TensorBoard instance running on port 6006. You need to kill it first and then start a new TensorBoard.

Comment: It says "Use '!kill 39216'  to kill it" but where do I have to type it?

Comment: I'm a beginer sorry if its an obvious question.

Comment: Either directly in the notebook. Commands starting `!` are actually command line calls. So, you can run the same command with the leading `"` in a command line (on the same machine).

Comment: This fixed my problem on version 2.10 on windows, nothing indicated that another instance was running on this port